# Why my code cannot find my file/directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to get code to read from a .txt file, the file itself is within another file called driving_dataset. The files exist and it should be able to find the .txt file but it won't and I cannot tell what I am doing wrong..

I have triple checked for any spelling errors

```
#read data.txt
with open("driving_dataset/data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        xs.append("driving_dataset/" + line.split()[0])
```

It should be directed through driving_dataset folder to the data.txt file but it does not pick it up. and gives me the error

```
with open("driving_dataset/data.txt","r") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'driving_dataset/data.txt'
```

Comment: try a full path instead of a partial one .. you are not where you think you are ...

Comment: Because of the `driving_dataset/data.txt` was a relative path. So make sure it can be found.Or maybe you can try to visit it by using absolute path.Like `/xxx/xxx/driving_dataset/data.txt`!

Comment: To check, if you use the right path type `import os` and the `print(os.path.isfile("driving_dataset/data.txt"))`. If you want to know in what folder you start with your script type: `print(os.listdir("."))`.